# How to disable image stretching In the application kivy-example/demo/pictures/main.py

Tags: python, image, kivy

Kivy is provided with some demo. In one of them kivy-example/demo/pictures/main.py, some images can moved and stretched. I [started to modify this app](http://dip4fish.blogspot.fr/2013/08/moving-chromosomes-with-kivy.html) . My question is how to disable image stretching ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set unwanted interactions to false: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scatter.html#control-interactions

Add to your .kv file:

```
<Picture>:
    # ...
    do_scale:False
    # ...
```

Or to your class:

```
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty

class Picture(Scatter):
    # ...   
    do_scale =  BooleanProperty(False)
```